# Magento 2 how to configure Nginx to allow execute other php files in root folder

Tags: magento2, nginx

How to configure nginx to let magento execute php files.

For example I created `phpinfo.php` and I'd like to execute it.

Where should I put it? `./` or `./pub/` ?

What do I need to write into the config ?

Comment: i know this is all depends, but, avoid creating any files like phpinfo.php in root. if you really need it to just check something, ok, but at least name it differently.

Comment: Sure, these all for dev. purposes on local or another dev. env.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use the official Nginx config (`nginx.conf.sample` file in the Magento 2 distribution) then you need change the *[**line 109**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1.0.0-beta/nginx.conf.sample#L109)* from :

```
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
```

to :

```
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503|phpinfo)\.php$ {
```

and place `phpinfo.php` to the `pub` subfolder because `pub` declared as document root at *[**line 21**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1.0.0-beta/nginx.conf.sample#L21)*:

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

I use *[**my own Nginx config**](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/24)* for Magento 2 and it permits `phpinfo.php` in the root folder.

Comment: this is pretty interesting, magento 2 sample nginx config allows me to browse and download whole magento shop.

Comment: @Mage2.PRO I have somewhat related question to your answer posted, can please look at my post, and maybe suggest something? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/197290/32271 Thank you.

Answer (score -5):

Don't be confuse so much. I have done magento2 installation with nginx and varnish caching.
Please follow the below steps.

Step 1-:
Install required packages

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
$ sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:duggan/composer
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y php5-fpm nginx varnish php5-gd php5-intl php5-mcrypt php5-xsl mysql-server php5-curl php5-json php5-composer
$ sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Step 2-:
Create a database to install magento2.

```
mysql -p -e "create database magento2"
```

Step 3-:
Varnish server setup.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/varnish
```

Default configuration replace from

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
-T localhost:6082 \
-f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
-S /etc/varnish/secret \
-s malloc,256m"
```

To

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,1024m"
```

Check default.vcl file port

```
nano /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

Output-:

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
```

Configure the nginx.conf to listen port **8080**.

Comment: Thx for your post, but I asked not that

Comment: Click on my Article link. I have added nginx.conf for nginx server.

Comment: @ArvindRawat Stack Exchange is not a place to promote your site

Comment: @andyjv I am not promoting here. I wish to post whole configuration file here. But it need more line indentation.

Comment: Nevertheless your post doesn't answer on my question. Voting for spam